# Al hacer scroll en un RecyclerView los elementos cambian de posicion

Tags: android

Tengo un recyclerview en el cual tengo unos items, al dar click a cualquiera de ellos, aparece un imageview en el item seleccionado, esta parte ya la logre hacer pero mi problema es que al hacer scroll hacia abajo y volver a subir el elemento que se hizo visible se duplica en otros items que no he seleccionado. ¿Como podría solucionar esta situación?. De antemano gracias.

Cuando selecciono el item.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se duplica en otro item.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo del adaptador:

```
public class EmployeeRecyclerViewAdapter extends
                                         RecyclerView.Adapter<EmployeeRecyclerViewAdapter
                                                 .ViewHolder> {

    private List<Employee> mEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
    private ClickItem clickItemAc;
    private View viewGeneral;

    public EmployeeRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Employee> employeeList,ClickItem clickItem) {
        this.mEmployees.addAll(employeeList);
        this.clickItemAc = clickItem;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Employee employee = mEmployees.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(employee.getName());
        holder.role.setText(employee.getRole());
    }

    public void updateEmployeeListItems(List<Employee> employees) {
        final EmployeeDiffCallback diffCallback = new EmployeeDiffCallback(this.mEmployees, employees);
        final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback);

        this.mEmployees.clear();
        this.mEmployees.addAll(employees);
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mEmployees.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements ClickItem {

        private final TextView role;
        private final TextView name;
        private final ImageView status;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            viewGeneral = itemView;
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.employee_name);
            role = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.employee_role);
            status = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);

            name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    clickItemAc.clickItem(viewGeneral);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void clickItem(View v) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu `Adapter` tienes un método que modifica el listado original, te recomiendo agregar `notifyDataSetChanged()` para que se realice la actualización correctamente y lo veas reflejado en tu `ListView`:

```
public void updateEmployeeListItems(List<Employee> employees) {
    final EmployeeDiffCallback diffCallback = new EmployeeDiffCallback(this.mEmployees, employees);
    final DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(diffCallback);

    this.mEmployees.clear();
    this.mEmployees.addAll(employees);
    diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);

   notifyDataSetChanged(); //*** Agregar.
}
```